# Trying to display the registered name in my home screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi so I have an application where the person registers himself and gets taken to the home screen where I have a flatlist of everyone who has registered. I want to make it so that it can display the users name who has signed in on the home screen like Welcome {user}. I am still a beginner so any help would be useful. Here is my code:-

Sign Up Screen:-

```
function SignupScreen(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const sendCred = async (props) => {
    fetch('http://10.0.0.2/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(async (data) => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
          props.navigation.navigate('Home');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error', e);
        }
      });
  }; 
  return (
        <TextInput
          label="Email"
          mode="outlined"
          value={email}
          style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18 }}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: 'blue' } }}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
          label="password"
          mode="outlined"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setPassword(text);
          }}
          style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18 }}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: 'blue' } }}
        />
        <TextInput
          label="Name"
          value={name}
          mode="outlined"
          onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
          style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18 }}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: 'blue' } }}
        />
);
}
```

Home Screen:-

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('http://10.0.0.2/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((results) => {
        setData(results);
        setName(results.name);
        setLoading(false);

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        Alert.alert('something went wrong in HomeScreen_fetchData()');
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const renderList = (item) => {
    return (
      <Card
        style={styles.mycard}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile', { item })}>
        <View style={styles.cardView}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 60, height: 60, borderRadius: 50 / 2 }}
            source={{
              uri: item.picture,
            }}
          />
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text>{item.position}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Card>
    );
  };
  
  return (
      <CustomHeader title="Home" />
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        
        <Text>Your name is {name}</Text>

        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return renderList(item);
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
          onRefresh={() => fetchData()}
          refreshing={loading}
        />
      </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const sendCred = async (props) => {
    ...........
      .then(async (data) => {
        try { 
          // expect "data.user" is an object contain user related data like "name" etc ...
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user) ); // store user here
          props.navigation.navigate('Home');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error', e);
        }
      });
  };
```

Home Screen:-

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  .........
  const [user, setUser] = useState({}); // new add

  const getUser = async () => {
    try { 
          const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user'); // get user here
          setUser(JSON.parse(data) );
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error', e);
        }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);
 
  
  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        
        <Text>Welcome {user && user.name ? user.name : ""}</Text> // expect user object has "name" property 

        .....
      </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: No didn't work. It gave me this error:- null is not an object (evaluating 'user.name')

Comment: It's just to give you an idea of how could it be imlemented. I have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

**This will work only if you have a jwt token**

Once you did that (we assume that you had stored the user in the token):

```
.then(async (data) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
      props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

You can create a file that will return the current user (e.g. Service/auth.service.js), we use **jwt-decode** (you need to import from nmpjs) that will decode the token :

```
/**
* Return current user
*/
const getCurrentUser = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    return jwtDecode(token);
};

export default {getCurrentUser}
```

You can then import it into your Home component like this :

```
import AuthService from "hereThePath/Services/auth.service"


const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
console.log(`this is the user name ${user.name}`);
```